# Filter Excel table if select cell values are true using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have an Excel table with a list of multiple rating agencies in a column (Field 3, "Framework/Agency" in my book). Outside of the table, I have 5 rows, one for each agency, and a cell to the right with a drop-down menu containing only "Yes." Essentially, the only options for these five cells are "Yes" or blank. I would like to filter the table to include any agencies that are marked as "Yes" in column 2 and to exclude any agencies that are left blank. If all are blank, I would like the table to not be filtered by agency, as I have another set of macros that I am using on other columns.

An example of my other, more basic macros:

```
If Range("d4").Value = "" Then Range("Database").AutoFilter Field:=18
If Range("d4").Value <> "" Then .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=Range("d4").Value
```

D4 is equal to another criteria that I have, and it filters field 18 in my table. My overall workbook looks something like this.

```
Col1       Col2

Agency 1    Yes
Agency 2
Agency 3    Yes
Agency 4   
Agency 5

Col1       Col2     Col3 (column desired to be filtered    Col4    Col5    Col6 (also filtered using another macro)
XXX        YYY      Agency 1                               ZZZ     AAA     BBB
XXX        YYY      Agency 3                               ZZZ     AAA     BBB
XXX        YYY      Agency 3                               ZZZ     AAA     BBB
XXX        YYY      Agency 1                               ZZZ     AAA     BBB
```

Given the circumstances above (A2:B7 in my book), I would like to see the results for only agencies 1 and 3, along with any other filters I have in my other filtering macros. As values change in column 2, I would like to see the results change as well.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: 1.) Write a title that summarizes the specific problem:
“Filter Excel table if any value in a cell is true using VBA”
2.) Introduce the problem before you post any code
" I have an Excel table with a list of multiple rating agencies in a column (Field 3, "Framework/Agency" in my book). Outside of the table, I have 5 rows, one for each agency, and a cell to the right with a drop-down menu containing only "Yes." Essentially, the only options for these five cells are "Yes" or blank..."

Comment: 3.) Help others reproduce the problem
I drew out, to the best of my abilities, a recreation of the table I am looking at currently
4.) Include all relevant tags
I think that “Excel,” “VBA,” and “Filtering” are all relevant to my question.
5.) Proof-read before posting!
Sure, there are some minor uses of unconcise language, but I believe that my point is clear
6.) Post the question and respond to feedback
I am responding to your feedback now.
7.) Look for help asking for help
It appears that this is what we are doing now. Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would add a helper column to the end of your table that uses the Countifs formula to determine if the value in Col3 is in your check range and Col2 of your check range is = "yes".  So assuming your check range is A1:B5 and your first Agency to check is in C9 then the formula would be =COUNTIFS(A1:A5,C9,B1:B5,"yes")>0

then you can just filter for true and you can also hide that helper column if you need to.

As for the filter updating when values in the range change check out.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change

Comment: Hi Bee_Riii--Yes, that is exactly what I did-Essentially a dummy column with a boolean argument. I would have added my answer, but the question was locked. Thank you for your help, regardless!